# Unable to use Googles Nearby Messages API with SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui, google-nearby

I am unable to use Googles Nearby Messages API with SWIFTUI. Using it with Storyboard was not an issue as it used to work without any problems. however with SWIFTUI, I get an error message " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectNotAvailableException', reason: 'UIAlertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications, please use UIAlertController!'".

Comment: If it's the Google Nearby Messages library and not your own code that is using `UIAlertView`, it sounds like you'd have to use only `AppDelegate` code and not `SceneDelegate`. I would think it'd be possible to still use SwiftUI, but definitely not the SwiftUI lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you. Your guess is right. It is Google Nearby Message that is calling this code. I just also found that Google provides facility to call Alerts created by user, which I had overlooked. I am now trying that. Hopefully, it should help solve the issue.